# How do I prevent some branches from ever being fetched by others?

Tags: git

With `Git`, I know you can specify only to selectively fetch a few branches from others. But if your tree is a remote to others, how do you prevent some branches from being fetched by others? Like just hiding a few.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good way to restrict read (fetch) on per branch basis in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234092/is-there-a-good-way-to-restrict-read-fetch-on-per-branch-basis-in-git)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Git itself, you can't.
Even with an authorization layer like [Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/master-toc.html), you cannot restrict *read* access to branches.

That means the general principle behind DVCS (Distributed VCS) repo holds true:
If you have somehow access to a repo, you have read access to *all* its content.

Keeping the confidential content in a separate repo remains the surest way to have that content never fetched, as mentioned in "[Is there a good way to restrict read (fetch) on per branch basis in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234092/is-there-a-good-way-to-restrict-read-fetch-on-per-branch-basis-in-git)"

Comment: Thanks. Keeping another repo is a good idea. It serves my purpose well.